# Aptana Studio 3 newproject error with Django

Tags: python, django, windows-7-x64, aptana3

I am having an issue with starting a new project from the command prompt. After I have created a virtual env and activated the enviroment, when I enter in .\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject new_project, a popup window shows up which says "AptanaStudio3 executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library"

I have tried uninstalling Aptana studio, but even when it is uninstalled, the error still occurs. Not sure what I need to do fix this. I have not unistalled/reinstalled python, i'm not even sure if that has anything to do with it. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, finally figured out that the default program to run the django-admin.py was aptana studio 3, even though the program had supposedly been uninstalled completely from my system. I changed the default program to be the python console launcher and now it works fine. There goes 2 hours down the drain..